# How can we get pixi-viewport to follow a pixi-react component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, viewport, pixi.js, react-ref

Working on a game, I have a map and a viewport following a character, which moves on the map.

I made a working prototype here: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-wave-lkkgs?file=/src/index.js  (click on the browser tab, then use the keyboard arrows to move the text)

Problems I encountered:

- Forced to use the class-based style PixiComponent as wrapper around pixi-viewport's Viewport class, when my codebase is entirely written with functions and hooks.
- refs hell in the MyViewport component (even had to use an external package use-callback-ref to get this working).
- Forced to re-rerender MyViewport for its refs to have a DOM node attached, before I can have the callback executed for the viewport to start following the text.

I believe that all the complexity is introduced by using PixiComponent, and that a hook-like rewrite of ReactViewport might even avoid the need for refs.
This appears possible given this message from the creator of @inlet/react-pixi:

[image]

But I haven't figured out how to do this rewrite yet.